# Android database not saving correctly

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have created a very simple android application which asks the user for their details such as name, number etc and saves it in a database then prints in on a different screen. However I am having some issues with the database, it seems that instead of overwriting the row in the database it seems to add the text in the same row for example I have a edit text for name I can enter: "James" and then save it. Then when I go back to overwrite e.g. change the details of the name to say something like "Ben" instead of overwriting the row it seems to add in the same row so its like 
"JimmyBen". Any Ideas how I could possibly change this?

Database Code:

```
package com.example.androidsimpledbapp1;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/*
 * Class for Working with DB 
 */

//Update each time DB structure changes e.g. adding new property
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
//DB Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "details.db";
//Table name
public static final String  TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
//DB Columns 
public static final String  COLUMN_ID = "_Id";
public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONNAME  = "firstName";
public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONBLOOD  = "bloodType";
public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONCONTACT  = "contactName";
public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONNUMBER  = "phoneNumber";
public static final String  COLUMN_PERSONRELATION = "relationship";

//Constructor
/*
 * Passing information to super class in SQL
 * Context is background information 
 * name of db 
 * Database version
 */
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

/*
 * What to do first time when you create DB
 * Creates the table the very first time
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)
 * Remember to use Commas as shown below
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            COLUMN_PERSONNAME + " TEXT, "+
            COLUMN_PERSONBLOOD + " TEXT, "+
            COLUMN_PERSONCONTACT + " TEXT, "+
            COLUMN_PERSONNUMBER + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PERSONRELATION + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    //Execute the query
    db.execSQL(query);
}

/*
 * If ever upgrading DB call this method
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
 */
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    //Delete the current table
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    //create new table 
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add new row to the database
public void addProduct(Details details){
    //Built in class - set values for different columns 
    //Makes inserting rows quick and easy
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSONNAME, details.get_firstName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSONBLOOD, details.get_bloodType());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSONCONTACT, details.get_contactName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSONNUMBER, details.get_phoneNumber());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSONRELATION, details.get_relationship());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

/*Table was deleted*/
public void deleteProducts(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();      
    db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, null);
}

//Take DB and Convert to String 
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    //Every Column and row
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    //First row point here, second row point here

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        //Extracts first name and adds to string
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"))!=null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
            c.moveToNext();
            /*
             * Displaying all other columns 
             */
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `addProduct` method uses [`db.insert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) which is always going to create a new row. There is also [`db.update`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) which is for modifying rows.

You will need to make sure you specify a proper `WHERE` clause so that the correct rows are modified. For a single row using the primary key is prefered which is usually the response from the `db.insert`.